# postgres - update a row based on other rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I am wondering, how to update a row where certain columns are empty, based on the values from other rows.

[image]

I want to update the columns (user_name, database_name, connection_from) for the first row with values in the below two rows. The session_id is same.

Thanks.

Comment: The critical part of this is understanding the data that you're trying to gather, not the update itself. If you figure out how to SELECT the data that you need, the UPDATE is simple. Without knowing the details of the table definition (notably the primary key) I can't be more specific.

BTW, you should consider storing the connection info as connection_ip inet and connection_port int; the inet type gives you some powerful operators.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather vague as to how you are choosing what values to update.  Let me assume that you are looking at the data based on `session_id` and any non-NULL value will work for those three columns:

```
update t
    set user_name = coalesce(t.user_name, tt.user_name),
        database_name = coalesce(t.database_name, tt.database_name),
        connection_from = coalesce(t.connection_from, tt.connection_from)
    from (select session_id, max(user_name) as user_name,
                 max(database_name) as database_name,
                 max(connection_from) as connection_from
          from t
          group by session_id
         ) tt
    where t.session_id = tt.session_id and
          (t.user_name is null or t.database_name is null or t.connection_from is null);
```

Comment: thank you very much. Almost worked. The connection_from column did not update. A small catch. The connection_from column though looks like null, when I issue select * from t where connection_from is null, no rows are returned. Can you guide me? Thanks again.

Comment: @vignesh28 . . . Replace the `coalesce()` with something like `case when t.connection_from > '' then t.connection_from else tt.connection_from end)`.